# php:function in XSLT to pass arguments directly, not in an array

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am having issues with how XSLT is passing arguments to my PHP function.  I am using `<xsl:value-of select="php:function('form::validate_add',@name,type,message)" />` to pass the attribute name, element type, and element message to a php function but the arguments being passed are large arrays including useless information for my needs.

**XML:**

```
<element name='text2-1'>
    <type>required</type>
    <message>The field Enter Text is required</message>
</element>
<element name='textarea'>
    <type>required</type>
    <message>The textarea is required</message>
</element>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="element">
   <xsl:value-of select="php:function('form::validate_add',@name,type,message)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

**PHP:**

```
public static function validate_add($name, $type, $message=NULL) {
#tmp
print_r($name);
}
```

Returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => DOMAttr Object
        (
            [name] => name
            [specified] => 1
            [value] => text2-1
            [ownerElement] => (object value omitted)
            [schemaTypeInfo] => 
            [nodeName] => name
            [nodeValue] => text2-1
            [nodeType] => 2
            [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
            [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
            [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
            [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
            [previousSibling] => 
            [attributes] => 
            [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
            [namespaceURI] => 
            [prefix] => 
            [localName] => name
            [baseURI] => 
            [textContent] => text2-1
        )

)
```

So it looks like the "value" key of the array is the correct value that I am after.  Is there any way to pass this argument directly rather than passing the entire array and having to extract the correct value from the array in the PHP function?  I would prefer not to alter my php function or add a new function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass string values of the DOM nodes from XPath/XSLT then use `<xsl:value-of select="php:function('form::validate_add', string(@name), string(type), string(message))" />`

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Do they have better documentation on this?  I can't seem to find anything at php.net.

Comment: I made that suggestion based solely on your debug output and my knowledge of XPath but as you ask for documentation, http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php has examples and explanations in the comment section, one saying "Last but not least, take a look at the 'string()' function I
called in XSL before passing it back. That is because without
calling that, when it runs it will try and pass the node object,
and not its value (which is what you most likely only want).".

Comment: Okay, I did see that page on php.net, but it did not have enough.  I assume studying XPath will assist me.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, didn't work for me...for whatever reason. nearly, but adding text() as well fixed it...

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:function ('ucfirst', string(path/element/text()))"/>
```

Need to add PHP namespace to stylesheet declaration:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
```